# how to display comment text to another page?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

i want to display the comment when we wrote on comment box after submit i need to display  what we wrote in comment box (it is working on database when i submit comment it will save to database i need that value to display under the comment box then i am using ajax for sending values to another page)

index.html

```
<html>
<body>
  <head>
    <script src="jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  </head>

<div class="wrapper"style=" margin: 0 auto;width: 1000px;">
    <div class="header"style="width:1000px;height:100px;background:#A6D1ED;"></div>
        <div class="main"style="width:1000px;height:400px;background:#EEEAF2;">

        <form name="form" method="post" action="insertcom.php">
           <textarea  name="comments"  id="comments"style="width:500px;height:100px;"></textarea>
           <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" id="btnS"/>
       </form>
            <div id="jcontent"></div>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                /* * Checking the Login - * */
                $('#btnS').on('click',function(e){
                    e.preventDefault();
                    var data_get = {
                            'comments': $('#comments').val().trim(),
                            <!-- 'username' : $('#username').val().trim(), -->
                            <!-- 'password' : $('#password').val().trim(), -->
                            <!-- 'email'        : $('#email').val().trim() -->
                            <!-- 'comments' : $('#comments').val().trim() -->
                            };
                    $.ajax({
                                url     : 'insertcom.php',
                                type    : 'POST',
                                data    : data_get,
                                timeout : 30000,
                                success : function(response_data, text, xhrobject) {
                                console.log(text);
                                if(text == "success"){
                                    $('#jcontent').html('success');
                                    }
                                else if(text == "ERROR"){
                                    $('#jcontent').html(' Fail ');
                                    }
                            }
                    });
                });
            </script>   
        </div>
        <div class="footer"style="width:1000px;height:100px;background:#7290A3;"></div>
    </div>  
<style>
h1{margin:0px;}     
</style>


</body>
</html>
```

insertcom.php

```
<?php

$host="localhost"; // Host name
$username="root"; // Mysql username
$password=""; // Mysql password
$db_name="713481"; // Database name
$tbl_name="test_four"; // Table name

// Connect to server and select database.
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect");
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

// Get values from form
$comments=$_POST['comments'];

// Insert data into mysql
$sql="INSERT INTO $tbl_name(comments)VALUES('$comments')";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

// if successfully insert data into database, displays message "Successful".
if($result){
echo "Successful";
echo "<BR>";
echo "<a href='insert.php'>Back to main page</a>";
}

else {
echo "ERROR";
}
?>

<?php
// close connection
mysql_close();
?>
```

please assist me this is my project........

Comment: Instead of `success`, return the html for comment box you want to add.

Comment: Whats wrong, your comment box is on the same page, so value should already be there?

Comment: i know that rohitcopyright  brother, but like facebook we sending massage when we send to our friends just the text are display there when we enter

Comment: On success return the json array echo {'comments':$comments} and in your ajax response use $('#your_comment_display_id').text(response_data.comments)

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your PHP script might be throwing an error that is not being caught by your ajax call. You are only giving a `success` handler for the `$.ajax()` call. Please, try passing also an `error` callback.

The error callback has this signature: `Function( jqXHR jqXHR, String textStatus, String errorThrown )`. You can see in detail at http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

EDIT: If your script has a problem then `textStatus` might tell you about the problem.

Answer (score 0):

try to show the response_data in success

$.ajax({
                                url     : 'insertcom.php',
                                type    : 'POST',
                                data    : data_get,
                                timeout : 30000,
                                success : function(response_data, text, xhrobject) {
                                console.log(text);
                                if(text == "success"){
                                    $('#jcontent').html(response_data);
                                    }
                                else if(text == "ERROR"){
                                    $('#jcontent').html('Insertion of the Fail of the India');
                                    }
                            }
                    });

Answer (score 0):

your code is working fine, your message is shown in comment area and success message below of it. To show response message from insertcom.php update JavaScript code as $('#jcontent').html(response_data); If you want to show same comment message on other pages of site write sql query to fatch data and display it.